# Highcharts plot offset on line graph with categories

Tags: highcharts

How can I have a line graph with categories, but plot the lines in between the categories label? Is there a way to offset the plot to the beginning of the tick width?
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jMcfG/1/
I want the line to begin on the origin on the x axis, just like it would if the categories wouldn't be there.

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [0,3,2,5]        
    }]
});
```

});​

Comment: Do you want your line to start at 0,0 point? the place where X and Y intersect?

Comment: yes, in this case the first point is 0,0 so I want it to start there. If the first point was 0,1 then I would expect it to start on the Y line at the first tick, if that makes sense. I want it to behave as if it didn't have the categories. If you take out the categories definition it will naturally move on to the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stick you chart to the bottom using threshold property.  Like this:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
        },
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            threshold: 0
        },

    },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0,3,2,5] 
        }]
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMcfG/5/

For x-axis this is not possible with use of an API.  You will need to do some custom programming. It's a feture that centers graph if categories are present.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it isn't the answer I wanted, but it is correct :)

Comment: Just wondering, when you are saying I would need to do some custom programming, what do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I did find an alternative solution which is to add an imaginary point which mirrors the first plot and then set the x axis min to 1 to cut it out, so the graph will cross the origin and will only be visible on the positive side.
http://jsfiddle.net/jMcfG/7/

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 1,
        categories: ['-13', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minPadding: 1
    },

    series: [{
        data: [-1,1,3,2,5]        
    }]
});
```

});​